# Difference between “wahr” and “echt”

Tags: difference, synonym

I’ve seen both translated as *true* or *authentic*; I would like to know what the difference is. If they are both synonyms, please clarify when you would use one over the other.

Comment: In German you can say that something is "echt wahr", that is, "really true".

Answer (score 18):

*Wahr* (true) is the opposite of *falsch* (false) while *echt* (authentic, real) is the opposite of *unecht* (fake, unreal).

Answer (score 9):

The word **wahr** is used to declare that a story or fact is true.

The word **echt** is more common for objects. Like if you have a real Rolex and not a replica.
So for example:

> Die Rolex ist echt!

This is the correct usage of *echt*.

> Die Rolex ist wahr!

This sentence is incorrect usage of *wahr*.

Comment: Ich bin älter als Du. -- Echt? Echt!

Comment: @Damon: Wirklich?

Comment: Do you maybe want to introduce another example where *wahr* works, but *echt* does not?

Comment: Damon, "Echt?" ist hier Umgangssprachlich. "Wirklich", wie Martjin es schon geschrieben hat, wäre korrekt. "Echt!" wiederum wäre nicht falsch, weil hier durch das Ausrufezeichen lediglich die Frage aus "Echt?" in eine Aussage umgewandelt wird ohne eine neue Aussage zu bilden.

Comment: @Jan: "Das einzig wahre Warsteiner". Although I'm not sure that nonsensical phrase is a good example, it's hard to understand what it means even for a native speaker. Or rather, it's _easy_ to understand, just not what they _meant to say_. There is only one Warsteiner, and it is a terrifyingly bad beer, too. However, "wahr" here probably means to imply the opposite, that it's the most truthful taste of beer. "Einzig" implies that they only have one beer in their brand that has this quality, although they most definitively want to say something _quite different_, too. :-)

Comment: "einzig wahre" is an old idiom, reaching back at least to the time of Luther( not Luther King), which implifies that the *wahrheit* of the sentence it's in is without a doubt. Often used in german translations of the bible, for example.

Answer (score 2):

*Wahr* is basicly a boolean-value which tells if the relations in a statement is correct or not.

*Echt* is validity of an object, not a statement.
*(EDIT: Depending on context, a statement can be an object in some cases, but this has nothing to do with german language in special.)*

E.g.: "I've got a new Volkswagen" can be both, *wahr*(true) and *unwahr*(false), depending on the state if I really got a new Volkswagen or not.
The Car itself can be *echt* and *unecht*(When the car is a forgery).

The statement "I've got a new Volkswagen" cannot be *wahr* if the car is not *echt*. But even if the car is *echt*, the statement could be *unwahr* if it's not mine or it's not new.

---

The Duden says:

ECHT:

> nicht nachgemacht, nicht imitiert; unverfälscht
>    reinrassig
>    wirklich [vorhanden]; nicht vorgetäuscht, nicht scheinbar

In english:

> not counterfeit, not an imitation, genuine
>     pedigree
>     real[existent], not faked, not seemingly

WAHR:

> der Wahrheit, Wirklichkeit, den Tatsachen entsprechend;
>     wirklich geschehen, nicht erdichtet, erfunden o. Ä.
>     tatsächlich, wirklich

In english:

> The truth, reality, in accordance with the facts
>     really happened, not conceived, contrived etc.

Comment: Was ist mit "Dazu kann ich keine echte Aussage machen." bzw. "Die Aussage wahr nicht echt so gemeint."?

Comment: "Dazu kann ich keine echte Aussage machen" bedeutet soviel wie, dass man keine Aussage machen kann, ohne dabei etwas falsches zu sagen, was den Inhalt der Aussage verfälschen würde(Fälschung da Lüge). Entsprechend ist das Adjektiv "echt" hier richtig angewendet, da es sich auf die Echtheit der Einzelinhalte der virtuellen Aussage bezieht, nicht auf die Wahrheit der Gesamtaussage. "Die Aussage war (nicht wahr) nicht echt so gemeint." ist falsch, es müsste "wirklich" heißen.

Comment: Es fehlt, dass Statements selbst auch Objekte sein können mit Echtheitsmerkmal. "Wirklich/Echt" steht umgangssprachlich auch für "wahr". Beide Dinge fehlen in der Antwort.

Comment: Alles kann ein Objekt sein, da geht es natürlich im den Kontext. Das hat aber mit den Eigenschaften der deutschen Sprache nichts zu tun. Umgangssprache ist Umgangssprache, ich beziehe mich auf Dudendeutsch, wie den Dudenauszügen ja zu entnehmen sein dürfte.

Comment: Umgangssprache ist natürlich mit zu erklären, da sie existiert und für den Fragesteller genauso interessant ist.

Comment: Wo steht das? Weder in der Frage, noch in den SE Leitfäden.  Es erstaunt mich, dass es dir nur in meinem Post auffällt, dass Umgangssprache fehlt, obwohl sie in keiner der aktuellen Antworten vorhanden ist.

Comment: Die Diskussion gilt natürlich für die anderen mit. Dafür gibt es auch keinen Leitfaden. Einfach einleuchtende Dinge ergeben sich auch ohne Regelwerk ganz pragmatisch.

Comment: @falkb Falls mit echt und wahr ver/getauscht der Sinn trotzdem verstanden wird - was umgangssprachlich mit vielen Audrücken geschieht - hebt das den Unterschied nicht auf. Unecht kann auch eine Aussage sein, die im Grunde nur eine Frage ist, oder ein Satz der keine Aussage hat, z.B. (Politiker-)Geschwafel. Um eine (echte) Aussage zu machen, muss ich etwas (inhaltlich) sagen. Dies sagt aber nichts über dessen Wahrheitsgehalt aus. Bsp. Hr. Meier hat gesagt, ... . Hat er wirklich (echt) ... gesagt, oder hat er es geschrieben? Ist es wahr, dass er ... gesagt hat, oder hast Du Dir das ausgedacht?

Comment: Es geht mir einfach darum, dass Antworten alle diese Dinge berücksichtigen müssen, weil sonst beim Fragesteller ein unvollständiges Bild aufgebaut wird. Komplexe Dinge erfordern komplexe Antworten. "Echt" nur mit Gültigkeit zu erklären, ist nicht richtig, usw.

Answer (score 1):

### Antonyms

`wahr` is the opposite of `falsch`. `echt` is the opposite of `unecht`.

Though knowing that translations can still be different, can they be synonyms?

### Let's see the dictionary

I used the dictionary to verify possible translations - [Leo](http://dict.leo.org) is a very popular online dictionary that I recommend.

Please check the translation of [wahr](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=wahr&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)

Please check the translation of [echt](http://dict.leo.org/ende/index_de.html#/search=echt&searchLoc=0&resultOrder=basic&multiwordShowSingle=on)

**Both 'wahr' and 'echt' have translations in common: 'true', 'genuine', 'real', 'sincere', 'truthful', 'authentic', ...**

> Note: The word `echt` is also used as a word in the English language,
>   with the same meaning as the German word `echt`.

They really might be synonyms, let's dig further in the German language bible.

### Der Duden

I recommend to use the [Duden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duden) - the bible of the German language.

Let's see what we can find there:

[wahr](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/wahr)

You will find loads of information about the usage, the meanings, examples  and others.
In particular it is said that `wahr` is a **synonym** to `echt`.

[echt](http://www.duden.de/suchen/dudenonline/echt)

Similarly you find information about usage, meanings, examples, etc.
In particular it is said that `echt` is a **synonym** of `wahr`.

### Oh dear, how confusing is this?

So they have different antonyms but are also synonyms. Welcome to the German language. Much of it can really only be learned by heart and practice.

In the Duden the last sections (on both pages) read `Bedeutungen, Beispiele und Wendungen`.

I recommend to refer to those sections for good examples of each meaning of the word. **In particular there are usages that were not mentioned in any of the answers here.** It is simply too much or complicated to cover.

Answer (score 0):

These two words are not the same.

The word *wahr* is the German word for *true* and is used to define a statement is a fact or not.

The word *echt* is used in normal sentences or in questions. First the questions: in the German language you can ask “Echt?”. This short question is used to ask your opposite if the statement is true or not. *Echt* is also the opposite for *nachgemacht/gefälscht* or in english *fake/imitation*.

On the other hand you can use *echt* to define an object or a person to be real and not in fantasy or in another dimension. So if something is not *echt* it is not real.

Comment: Dass die Wörter nun gar nichts miteinander gemein haben kann man auch nicht sagen. "Ein echter Freund" = "Ein wahrer Freund".

Comment: das ist so nicht richtig, denn ein echter freund heißt einfach das es in in unserer realen Welt gibt. Wahrer Freund, bedeutet das man mit dieser Person einiges erlebt hat und man sich auf sie/ihn verlassen kann.

Comment: @snickbrack: "Du bist ein echter Freund", should mention echter Frund without having him/her in real life or anything else, so for me it's wrong what you stated...

Comment: sorry but i can't get behind your message. Please clarify!

Comment: Ein "echter Freund" und ein "wahrer Freund" haben für mich als Muttersprachler schon denselben Klang, ich sehe da keinen praktischen Unterschied. In der ursprünglichen Antwort ist mir die Definition von "echt" unvollständig. "Echt" ist auch das Gegenteil von "nachgemacht/gefälscht", wie in "Echtleder" (wie würde man das übersetzen... "real leather" oder "actual leather", ich kenne nur das Gegenteil "faux leather").

Comment: Ich glaube kaum, das es eine genaue Übersetzung für z.B. `EchtLeder` gibt, aber dann eben Wort-zu-Wort-Übersetzungen. Es ging ja aber in der Frage darum, was `echt` und was `wahr` ist. Da wäre `nachgemacht/gefälscht` nur ein weiteres Beispiel gewesen, ich nehme es aber trotzdem mal auf ;)

Comment: genuine leather: https://www.google.com/search?q=genuine+leather&tbm=isch

Answer (score 0):

This is *wahr*:

> The flame that burns twice as bright burns half as dark.

This is *echt*:

> The flame that burns twice as bright burns half as long.

*Wahr* is more oriented to either plain logic or to subjectivity and belief, while *echt* is more oriented towards objectivity and authenticity.

Regarding the subjectivity of *Wahrheit*, read the last words in *Kierkegaard: Entweder - Oder*:

> "[...]; denn nur die Wahrheit, die erbaut, ist Wahrheit für dich."